# When to use writeValueAsString() method of ObjectMapper class and when to use String directly

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my project there are two types of code:

1. `HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(comment, headers);`

Here comment is of String type  and header is of HttpHeader Object.

2. `ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(om.writeValueAsString(comment), headers);`

I just want know which one will be better and why.

Comment: Neither. Just return the `Comment` and let the spring message converters do the conversion.

Comment: FYI, you should only `new ObjectMapper()` once. It's fairly expensive to instantiate `ObjectMapper`, and the instances are reusable. But also what the other comment says - just let Spring handle the conversion for you in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`writeValueAsString` writes it as a JSON-formatted string. For instance if I have a class Coordinate that looks like:

```
class Coordinate {
  private int x;
  private int y;
  // plus constructor and methods
}
```

then `om.writeValueAsString(new Coordinate(1, 2))` will produce something like

```
{ "x":1,"y":2 }
```

instead of whatever the `toString`  method produces.

So, when your client is expecting a JSON-formatted string, use `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString`.

Comment: Is it a typo that this starts with `writeObjectAsString` instead of `writeValueAsString`?

Comment: Thanks, @ArtOfWarfare, that has lain unnoticed for almost six years! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

comment : is request to return in server.

headers : type of comment json or xml ,html,Image ,multipart ... etc.

see this example :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestJson = null;
try {
    requestJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(Yourrequest);HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestJson, headers);
    LOGGER.info("send request to  url {} ", getUrl());
    YourTypeOfResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(URL_LOCAL,
            entity, YourTypeOfResponse.class);
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    LOGGER.error("JsonGenerationException occurred ", e);
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    LOGGER.error("JsonMappingException occurred ", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("IOException occurred ", e);
}
```

Comment: JAX-RS automatically serializes returned object classes, so you don't really need to do this. You definitely shouldn't make a new ObjectMapper for every request / response.